# symbol acronyms in alphabetical order

Tags: memoir, glossaries, acronyms

I am writing my thesis, I am a beginner in LaTeX. In the thesis template, the acronym is defined like this
[image]

The result as in the figure:
[image]

They aren't in alphabetical order.

I need to be in alphabetical order, I check in the code about acronyms, I didn't find anything only this:

[image]

What I should add to the code to get the symbols in alphabetical order?

Comment: Do you use `\z`, `\z2` and `\z3` later in your document? You'd be surprised at what they output.

Comment: I don't know what is it, I just fill the code as it is, I added my acronyms

Comment: Can you provide a minimal document that replicates the result? Sure you're using [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (because you tagged it as such). But we want something to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing; it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: you can not use digits in command names so that code looks very suspicious.

Comment: if you make the list by hand like that in a description then you need to order the lines yourself (your text editor should be able to sort the lines) but glossaries or similar packages would make and sort the  list automatically based on acronyms used in the document. But you need to fix your `\z2` usage which can not possibly work. (please don't show code as an image, make a small but complete document that shows the problem and add as text to your question)

Comment: my document has many file, one is 'memoirthesis.tex' where I find the \newcommand\mysymbol[3]{%
\protected\gdef#1{#2}%
\item[$#2$]#3} and every chapter has a file ,the file of monuclature\begin{description}
\mysymbol{\z}{\textbf{PV}}{Photovoltaic.}
\mysymbol{\z2}{\textbf{IEA } }{International Energy Agency.}
\mysymbol{\z2}{\textbf{IEC } }{International Electrotechnical Commission.}
\mysymbol{\z3}{\textbf{SKTM }}{Shariket Kahraba wa Taket Moutadjadida.}
\mysymbol{\z4}{\textbf{RE  }}{Renewable Energy.}\end{description}